# What does "has been loathe to fully distance itself from" mean?

Tags: expressions

The following sentence I read from Huff Post: "*Why Egypt Matters: The Implications Of The Protests*" gets me quite confused. I've made the key problem boldface. Hope someone can explain to me the position of the Obama administration and what the boldface part means.

> The Obama administration -- from Joe Biden, who refused to call Mubarak
>   a dictator, to Obama himself, who emphasized Egypt's role as an ally
>   -- **has been loathe to fully distance itself from Mubarak**, and finds itself in a difficult position, reports theAtlantic.

The original link of the article:
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/01/29/why-egypt-matters_n_815863.html#s232358&title=Strong_US_Ally

Comment: The link is effectively broken (at least it now contains none of the quoted here).

Answer (score 2):

Omitting the phrase set off in em dashes, the sentence becomes:

> The Obama administration has been loathe to fully distance itself from
>   Mubarak.

It uses *loathe* in this sense:

> **loath**, or **loth**; also **loathe**, *adj*. : characterized by unwillingness to do something contrary to one's tastes, likes, sympathies, or ways of
>   thinking

It means that the Obama administration has been unwilling to separate itself and U.S. interests from former Egyptian President Mubarak, a long-time U.S. ally.

Note that while *loath* (or, as Tim Lymington notes, *loth*) is likely the more common form to use in this context, you can make the case for *loathe* as well:

> **loathe**, tr. v. : to feel strong aversion for : have extreme disgust at

In this sense, the Obama administration would be averse to breaking ties with Mubarak.

Comment: In British English, I think *loth* is commoner, and *loathe* is not used precisely because of ambiguity (also, the pronunciation would be different.)

Comment: @TimLymington Oddly, the British edition of Macmillan doesn't list _loth_ as alternative to [_loath_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/loath). The pronunciations it lists do differ between British (/ləʊθ/) and American (/loʊθ/), however.

Comment: I've never seen the spelling *loathe* for the adjectival form -- and it's typically pronounced with the hard th (like "thick").  I've never seen *loth* at all.

Comment: @Malvolio Although I wouldn't use it myself, M-W Unabridged lists _loathe_ as an acceptable alternate spelling for the adjectival form of _loath_. I've seen _loth_, but I'm not sure if it was in a contemporary work.

Comment: I agree with Malvolio, I have only ever seen 'loath' - sometimes one variant carries the torch whilst the rest fall by the wayside. And the th is certainly unvoiced as in 'thick'.

Comment: @BarryBrown I think it's the reverse, "loath" has always been the correct spelling for the adjective and "loathe" is emerging as a common malapropism.